# how do I change the validation message from 'required' on max character limit?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I keep getting the message 'required' when the character validation of 'max'is exceeded, but I have specified 'message' /'tooLong' to say "max character limit is 2.

Any help?

My model:

```
    /**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        [['question_id', 'survey_instance_id'], 'required'],
        [['question_choice_id'], 'number'],
        [['question_choice_id'], 'required', 'when' => function($QuestionAnswer) {
            $Question = Question::findOne($QuestionAnswer->question_id);
            return $Question->isMultipleChoice;
        }],
        [['question_choice_id'], 'exist', 'targetClass' => QuestionChoice::className(), 'targetAttribute' => 'id'],
        [['answer'], 'string', 'max' => 1, 'tooLong' => 'Max character limit is 1'],
        [['answer'], 'required', 'when' => function($QuestionAnswer) {
            $Question = Question::findOne($QuestionAnswer->question_id);
            return !$Question->isMultipleChoice;
        }],
    );
}
```

[image: Error message with 2 characters]

Comment: Specify [whenClient](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#$whenClient-detail) for client side validation to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can customize your error message.

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['username', 'required', 'message' => 'Please choose a username.'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the error message didn't change. It still returns 'Required' when there is a custom error message